# what is difference between `django.test.APITestCase` and `rest_framework.test.TestCase` in `python-django`

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing, web-api-testing

What is the major difference in these test classes `django.test.TestCase` and `rest_framework.test.APITestCase` . which is Better to test my `views.py` ?
can you suggest me documentations to understand about these.

Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: As I know there is no APITestCase in django. Use rest_framework.test.APITestCase

Comment: sorry I modified my question. APITestCase in rest_framework and TestCase in Django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between rest_framework.test.APITestCase and django.test.testcases.TestCase in HTTP Client they use (source: [github](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.3/rest_framework/test.py#L342)).

With rest_framework APIClient it easier to test API than with Django Client. For example, less work with json responses. See more: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: I'm working on testing response.
I'm having 3python objects and i'll get 3 objects as response i need to check whether the same is coming or not.
can you say how to compare the reponse.data and python objects.

Comment: `assertEqual` with first and second responses, then `assertEqual` with second and third, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual

Answer (score 1):

APITestCase in rest_framework.test is to test the api's in the rest. It is specific for the api operations and api calls.
Django.test.TestCase is used to test the Django classes.